# Bootstrapped standard errors and p-value from weighted mann-whitney test

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr, statistics-bootstrap, modelr

I would like to bootstrap the p-value and standard errors from weighted Mann-Whitney U test.

I can run the test as: *weighted_mannwhitney(c12hour ~ c161sex + weight, efc)* which works fine, but am not entirely sure how I can run a bootstrapped version of the same to obtain a bootstrapped p-value for instance.

```
library(sjstats) # weighted Mann-Whitney
library(tidyverse) # main workflow, which has purrr and forcats (IIRC)
# library(broom) # for tidying model output, but not directly loaded
library(modelr) # for bootstrap


data(efc)
efc$weight <- abs(rnorm(nrow(efc), 1, .3))

# weighted Mann-Whitney-U-test ----
weighted_mannwhitney(c12hour ~ c161sex + weight, efc)


# Bootstrapping

set.seed(1000) # for reproducibility

boot_efc <- efc %>% bootstrap(1000) 


# Throws error!
boot_efc %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(c12hour = map(strap, ~weighted_mannwhitney(c12hour ~ c161sex + weight, data = .)),
                tidy = map(c12hour, broom::tidy)) -> boot_efc_out
```

**SIDE NOTE:** The package for the weighted Mann-Whitney test has its own bootstrap function which can be used as shown below to obtain **bootstrapped standard error** and **bootstrapped p-value**, but this is running a different function (mean), I could not adapt that for the weighted Mann-Whitney. Not sure if this helps

```
# or as tidyverse-approach
if (require("dplyr") && require("purrr")) {
  bs <- efc %>%
    bootstrap(100) %>%
    mutate(
      c12hour = map_dbl(strap, ~mean(as.data.frame(.x)$c12hour, na.rm = TRUE))
    )

  # bootstrapped standard error
  boot_se(bs, c12hour)

    # bootstrapped p-value
  boot_p(bs, c12hour)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```r
  library(sjstats) # weighted Mann-Whitney
library(tidyverse) # main workflow, which has purrr and forcats (IIRC)
# library(broom) # for tidying model output, but not directly loaded
library(modelr) # for bootstrap
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'modelr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:sjstats':
#> 
#>     bootstrap, mse, rmse


data(efc)
efc$weight <- abs(rnorm(nrow(efc), 1, .3))

# weighted Mann-Whitney-U-test ----
mw_full <- weighted_mannwhitney(c12hour ~ c161sex + weight, efc)


# Bootstrapping

set.seed(1000) # for reproducibility

boot_efc <- efc %>% bootstrap(1000) 

tmp <- boot_efc %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(c12hour = map_dbl(strap, 
                              ~sjstats:::weighted_mannwhitney.formula(c12hour ~ c161sex + weight, 
                                                                      data = .$data[.$idx, ])$estimate))

boot_p(tmp$c12hour)
#   term   p.value
# 1    x 0.0316659
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Note that one of the problems comes from the way `weighted_mannwhitney()` works inside the `map()` function.  When it's called, it calls the `default` method rather than the `formula` method and then generates an error.  You can call the `formula` method for the statistic as I did in the code.  The other problem is that each `strap` element of `boot_efc` isn't a single data frame, it has two elements `data` and `idx` where the `idx` element are the bootstrapped observation numbers.  So, you need to use `.$data[.$idx, ]` as the bootstrapped data. The rest follows along from the example you posted.

Comment: This is certainly wrong! Since `sjstats::boot_p` obviously still computes t-statistics first and then draws from the Student t-distribution to get a p-value (moreover using B - 1 degrees of freedom), applying it to existing t-statistics makes no sense to me.

Comment: @jay.sf is right, my apologies.  It should work if you replace `$statistic` with `$estimate`.  I've edited the answer.

Comment: It still uses B - 1 degrees of freedom (DOF), where in this case B=1000, whereas the true DOF are 899. Even if this were corrected, the group sizes of individual bootstrap repetitions differ. Maybe a [permutation test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/33569) is feasible. Answering this question is treading on thin ice though and should be left to an experienced statistician or at least to Cross Validated.

Comment: Totally agree.  I saw the question as - how do I get this code to work.  I provided an answer to that.  I was going to propose a permutation test, because that also seemed more reasonable to me, but the question wasn't what's the right test.  I agree it wouldd be worth proposing a similar question on CrossValidates.

Comment: Thank you @jay.sf  for pointing this out - I appreciate it. As DaveArmstrong correctly pointed out, my question was more of how to do, so my fault on that front. I shall consult a statistician to have this properly addressed.